# Plot two timeseries with different x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot

I really can't find a solution to this:
I need to plot a timeseries of three years daily data on the same plot as three years monthly data (same y-scale = euros), but tried all the other threads talking about this without being able to figure it out. Any help?

It would be nice if the x-axis said the months, but numbers are just fine if it's too complicated...

thanks
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
t = 1:365*3; %// example without leap year
y = randn(size(t)); %// example data

plot(linspace(1,37,numel(t)),y) %// x axis with 36 month periods
xlim([1,37])

set(gca,'xtick',1.5:4:37) %// ".5" to place tick at middle of each month
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'Jan','May','Sep'})
```

[image]

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU!!!! (not the month thing, but anyhow now I can plot the month data over the daily data!)